# Grails - Pull data and display it?

Tags: mysql, grails

I'm using Grails. I want to pull information from a database on a class called "User" and simply display it. The data is stored in a MySql database. I can connect to it, and so can my application.

The controller "UserController", which has the business logic, has an action called "User". It looks like this:

```
import gorm.*


class UserController {
    static scaffold = true
    static defaultAction = "user"


    def index() {
       ...
    }

    def user() {
        try {

            def userToDisplay = User.get(1)
            return userToDisplay
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Something went wrong! ", e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

In my mind, GetUser should simply get the User with an id of 1 (which DOES exist in the database). The contents of that user should be displayed in a view, also called "user". It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>User info</title>
</head>
<body>
    Last Name: ${User.lastName}<br/>
    First Name: ${User.firstName}<br/>
    E-mail: ${User.email}<br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting an error message which says the following:

```
| Error 2014-01-27 13:04:07,089 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request:   
[GET] /TaskCheck/user
Cannot get property 'lastName' on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Cannot get property 'lastName' on null object
```

In other words, it keeps thinking that the "User" object that *should* have been pulled form the database is always null. I can't think of any code that I missed.

Can you tell me what I missed?? Did I miss some code in the UserController? This should have taken all of five minutes to do, but it's taken me MUCH longer than that. Thanks.

Comment: You have the C and V of MVC, M is missing. :) Have a look at [`render`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you have no model being returned to your view. Try something like this (and take a look at the user guide too).

```
def user() {
    def model = [:]
    try {

        model['user'] = User.get(1)
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Something went wrong! ", e.message)
    }

    render view: 'user', model: model
}
```

Then in your view you can access your model like this:

```
${user.lastName}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, dmahapatro &  Joshua Moore.

A model is returned to a view using "render", with a view and a model. Both of you were right. My answer was:

```
class UserController 
{
static defaultAction =  "user"

...

def user()
{
    try
    {

        def userToDisplay = User.get(1)
        render view: "user", model: [User:userToDisplay]
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Something went wrong! ", e.message)
    }
}

}
```

I kept trying to do it with a return statement, like I'd use in all the other languages.

I need to work harder to get rid of my .Net habits.

Comment: Just FYI BobaFett you can do that. You just need to return it as a map: `return [User:userToDisplay]`